# Is there something similar to python's enumerate for linq

Tags: .net, python, linq

In python I can easily get an index when iterating e.g.

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [(char, i) for i, char in enumerate(letters)]
[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
```

How can I do something similar with linq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. There is an [overload of `Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that takes a `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` to project an element together with its index:

For example:

```
char[] letters = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
var enumerate = letters.Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i });
foreach (var result in enumerate) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("Char = {0}, Index = {1}", result.Char, result.Index)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
Char = a, Index = 0
Char = b, Index = 1
Char = c, Index = 2
```

Comment: In C# 7.0 or later, you can do this with a little less code: `foreach (var (c, i) in letters.Select((c, i) => (c, i)))` (uses "tuple deconstruction")

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the overload of [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) which provides an index variable.  This provides access to the index, which you can use to generate a new anonymous type.  The following compiles and runs properly:

```
static void Main()
{

    var letters = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    var results = letters.Select((l, i) => new { Letter = l, Index = i });

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", result.Letter, result.Index);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```